# How to generate sitemap for a given domain by java what are the API s or Source codes available

Tags: java, web-crawler, sitemap

Hi Um quite new to java and um looking to build a site map generator when a user enters a domain.Um looking for a source code and an API to do this. I will be grateful if anyone can help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download

```
JDK 6
sitemapgen4j-1.0.1.jar
```

Example :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Date;

import com.redfin.sitemapgenerator.ChangeFreq;
import com.redfin.sitemapgenerator.WebSitemapGenerator;
import com.redfin.sitemapgenerator.WebSitemapUrl;

public class SitemapGenerator {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    WebSitemapGenerator webSitemapGenerator = WebSitemapGenerator.builder("http://www.example.com", new File("C:\\sitemap"))
    .gzip(true).build();

    WebSitemapUrl webSitemapUrl = new WebSitemapUrl.Options("http://www.example.com/test1.html")
      .lastMod(new Date()).priority(1.0).changeFreq(ChangeFreq.HOURLY).build();

    webSitemapGenerator.addUrl(webSitemapUrl);
    webSitemapGenerator.addUrl("http://www.example.com/test2.html");
    webSitemapGenerator.write();
  }
}
```

For more : http://code.google.com/p/sitemapgen4j/

Comment: What if you want to use an existing sitemap.xml file and add urls to it? Is there an option like that in sitemapgen4j? Thanks.

Comment: but how to display this in footer?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Heritrix, which is an open source web crawler written in Java. It supports advanced features like interpreting 'robots.txt' files, and comes with a bunch of very useful command line tools.

[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritrix)

[Heritrix homepage](https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/display/Heritrix/Heritrix)